# How to make a request with PHPLeague oAuth2 client?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

I'm integrating with a affiliate platform for a client which provides an oAuth2 API, don't usually do massive amounts of work with oAuth2.

I've decided for my client, I'll use the PHP Leagues oAuth2 package: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

Anyway, I've got an accessToken no problem! using the following:

```
   $provider = new GenericProvider([
        'clientId' => $this->config->affiliates->rakuten->clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $this->config->affiliates->rakuten->clientSecret,
        'redirectUri' => 'http://www.newintoday.com/',
        'urlAuthorize' => 'https://api.rakutenmarketing.com/token', // Ignore
        'urlAccessToken' => 'https://api.rakutenmarketing.com/token',
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://api.rakutenmarketing.com/' // Ignore
    ]);

    try {
        // Try to get an access token using the resource owner password credentials grant.
        $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('password', [
            'username' => $this->config->affiliates->rakuten->username,
            'password' => $this->config->affiliates->rakuten->password,
            'scope' => $this->config->affiliates->rakuten->publisherId,
        ]);

        $productSearchApiBaseUri = 'https://api.rakutenmarketing.com/productsearch/1.0';

        $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest('GET', $productSearchApiBaseUri, $accessToken, [
            'body' => '?keyword=shirt',
        ]);

        \Utils::dump($provider->getResponse($request));

    } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

My question is once we have the accessToken what do we use in it to make the request, I followed through the code and came up with the above but the API responds saying that the keyword is not specified? Is

```
$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest('GET', $productSearchApiBaseUri, $accessToken, [
    'body' => 'keyword=shirt',
]);
```

The correct way to provide it with a GET variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised I could simply include the get vars in the URI alla:

```
$productSearchApiBaseUri = 'https://api.rakutenmarketing.com/productsearch/1.0?keyword=shirt';
```